# Profunctors as a Kleisli bicategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, yoneda-lemma, profunctors

There is some discussion [on the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion#free_cocompletion_as_a_pseudomonad) on seeing the free cocompletion $\mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{A}) = [\mathbf{A}^{op}, \mathbf{Sets}]$, as a pseudomonad.  The Yoneda embedding $よ \colon \mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{A})$ gives the unit and that the multiplication would be the unique functor $\mu \colon \mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{A})) \to \mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{A})$ such that $\mu \circ よ = \mathrm{id}$. However, this creates some size issues.

On the other hand, composition of profunctors $p \colon \mathbf{B} \to \mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{A})$ and $q \colon \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{B})$ can be defined (following Remark 5.6 in [This is the (co)end...](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503)) as $\mathsf{Lan}_よ(p) \circ q$, which looks like composition in a Kleisli category for the (pseudo)monad.

Can we get the bicategory of profunctors as a Kleisli construction over the free-completion pseudomonad? Can we deal somehow with the size issues? Is there any reference where this construction is discussed?

Comment: out of curiosity, what goes wrong if you fix a cardinal kappa and try to execute this plan for kappa-accessible categories, kappa-accessible presheaves, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This beautiful story take place in $\mathsf{Cat}$, the bicategory of locally small categories. There, the construction of [**small presheaves**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+presheaf) induces a pseudomonad whose pseudoalgebrabas are *cocomplete categories* and whose Kleisli category is $\mathsf{Prof}$. A part of this story is folklore and is partially discussed in [Lex Colimits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0778), by Garner and Lack, Prop 2.2.

Another part of this story is explained in [Relative pseudomonads, Kleisli bicategories, and substitution monoidal structures](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-017-0361-3), with the relative approach, that tends to complicate a bit the things but shows a very nice direction.

Comment: Prof generally refers to the bicategory whose objects are *small* categories and whose morphisms are profunctors, so it is only a full sub-bicategory of the Kleisli bicategory for the "small presheaves" pseudomonad, which has all locally small categories as objects and "small profunctors" as morphisms.  The "relative" version is a good answer to the question on its own, but I don't think it uses the small-presheaf technology.

Answer (score 2):

A nice account of this is given in Martin Hyland's [Elements of a theory of algebraic theories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397514001807).