# Size issue in exhibiting the free cocompletion as a left adjoint

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

Consider the following well-known statement:

> Let $C$ be a small category, $E$ a cocomplete category, and $F\colon C\to E$ a functor. Then there is a (up to isomorphism) unique cocontinuous functor $F'\colon \mathbf{Set}^{C^\mathrm{op}}\to E$ such that $F'\circ y \cong F$, where $y\colon C\to \mathbf{Set}^{C^\mathrm{op}}$ is the Yoneda embedding.

*Question:* Is there a way to phrase this as an adjunction (between bicategories, of course)?

*Idea:* Consider the bicategory $\mathbf{SmallCat}$ of small categories and functors and the bicategory $\mathbf{CocompCat}$ of cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors. Then the above statement almost states that $C\mapsto \mathbf{Set}^{C^\mathrm{op}}$ is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor $\mathbf{CocompCat}\to \mathbf{SmallCat}$, *except* that this forgetful functor isn't well-defined: the underlying category of a cocomplete category isn't small.

How can one fix this size issue?

Comment: It's a [*relative* pseudoadjunction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.03678).

Comment: This is part of an adjunction between (possibly large) categories and (possibly large) categories with *small* colimits (and small colimit preserving functors between them). You may restrict to locally small categories to keep things simple. The left adjoint assigns to each locally small category $C$ the category of *small* presheaves (i.e. those which are small colimits of representable ones). If $C$ is small, all presheaves on $C$ are small, which is why we get the usual universal property of presheaves on a small category as a particular case.

Comment: Just choose the construction of small presheaves. Then everything works with locally small categories. Anyhow, this question should be closed, because it's a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti If it's a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate it would be more appropriate and polite to just link the original thread.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski Thank you so much for this very helpful comment! In fact, it's a completely well-written and totally satisfactory answer. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profunctors as a Kleisli bicategory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334864/profunctors-as-a-kleisli-bicategory)

Comment: @varkor Not at all. I wouldn't have recognized that as an answer to my question since I don't know about profunctors, Kleisli bicategories, pseudomonads, pseudoalgebras, Prof, ... As I said, Cisinski's comment answers my question. :-)

Comment: @varkor Can you explain your comment about relative pseudoadjunctions? For what do I need relative pseudoadjunctions? Cisinski's approach seems to avoid them and is very elegant.

Comment: @user984603: if you read even the introduction of the paper I linked, you would see it is answering exactly your question, and introduces the concept of relative pseudoadjunction. Cisinksi's comment is a corollary of the results of that paper.

Comment: The "does this answer your question" comment was automatically generated by MathOverflow; I didn't spot that it had been posted, sorry. You can ignore the part about profunctors, but the size issues it asks about are exactly the same as the size issues you ask about (an adjunction between bicategories is called a "pseudoadjunction" and generates a "pseudomonad").

Comment: @varkor But only experts will know that that's the same answer in disguise. :) Thanks for the paper. I'll read the introduction then.

Comment: @varkor The introduction to the paper is very unhelpful to me. Every second word is unknown to me. Do you expect me to google each of these terms? That would take me days. "Cisinksi's comment is a corollary of the results of that paper." Which result are you referring to (which theorem in the paper)?

Comment: @user984603: since you were asking questions about (pseudo)adjunctions between bicategories, I had expected you were familiar with 2-categorical terminology. Even if not, if you just ignore the prefix "pseudo" in the introduction, most of the words are standard category theory terms. But if you're satisfied with Cisinksi's comment, then it doesn't matter :) (It follows from Example 3.9 of that paper.)

Comment: @varkor Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Denis-Charles says in the comments, the best way to handle this is to replace the presheaf category $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{\mathrm{op}}}$ by the full subcategory $\hat{C}$ of small presheaves. By definition, a presheaf is **small** if it satisfies any of these equivalent conditions:

- it is a small colimit of representables;
- it is the left Kan extension of its restriction to some small full subcategory of $C$;
- it is the left Kan extension of some presheaf on some small category along some functor into $C$.

Every presheaf on a small category is small. But, for instance, a presheaf on a large discrete category is small iff its support is small; hence the terminal presheaf is not small.

The functor $C \mapsto \hat{C}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor
$$
(\text{cocomplete locally small categories}) \to (\text{locally small categories}),
$$
in a suitable 2-categorical sense.

A standard reference for this is:

> Brian J. Day and Stephen Lack. [Limits of small functors.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610439) *Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 210 (2007), 651–663.

But it goes back further than 2007. The introduction to Day and Lack's paper recounts some of the history.